# User is unable to select multiple answers from list menu using Mac OS and Firefox browser in self registration form

Tags: jquery, html, css

User is not able to select multiple answers from list menu using Mac OS and Firefox browser in one registration form.

As shown in screenshot [image: list item screenshot]

when user select one item that will working fine but when he try to select multiple answers from list menu using Mac OS and Firefox browser he is not able to select that.

Please suggest.

Please find the codesnapShot also:

[image]

Comment: Hello, please include the code that is not working as intended into the question. With the current problem description, one can only guess, what the problem might be - which is not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I have added code snapshot above  by name "codesnapShopImage" . Kindly check and let me know.

Comment: This Issue is with Dojo Multiple select which is coming on combination of Mac with firefox browser . This is working fine on window.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to select multiple items from a `select` element then you have to set `multiple` attribute on the select element.

```
<select multiple name="something" id="something">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
        <option value="option4">option4</option>
        <option value="option5">option5</option>
    </select>
```

Now user can select multiple items by holding `ctrl` key.
There is a jquery plugin called chosen which makes select boxes more userfriendly. You can read it's documentation [here](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Comment: Thanks for reply But No This is not the case. We have not used this . I have share the code snapshot kindly check.